# Azure DevOps API Email Sending Issue - Email Not Sent Through CURL command

Tags: curl, azure-devops

StackOverflow community,

Today, I'm integrating the Azure DevOps API into a new workflow to automate email notifications via a Bash script in an ADO pipeline. Despite multiple tests and online searches (including [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/send-mail/send-mail?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0#emailrecipients) as well), I've encountered a roadblock where the script completes without errors, but the email fails to send= and I think the "--data" value (CURL command) is the responsible:

**Code Snippet:**

```
ADO_API=$(echo "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/wit/sendmail?api-version=7.1-preview.1")               
 curl --request POST "$ADO_API" \
              --header "Authorization: Bearer $SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" \
              --header "Accept: application/json" \
              --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
              --data '{"message": "{\"to\":{\"emailAddresses\":[\"my_email_address\"]},\"subject\":\"Test email\",\"body\":\"Empty body\",\"replyTo\":{\"emailAddresses\":[\"my_email_address\"]}}"}'
```

**Execution Outcome:**

The script task concludes successfully.
No email is sent to the intended recipient (emailAddresses).
The following output is exposed on the ADO Pipeline console:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   394  100   212  100   182   2294   1969 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4329
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: clientMessage","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
Finishing: drift checking
```

I've already tried several troubleshooting steps, but I couldn't find a solution.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or can offer insight related to how modify the "--data" value in order to send a simple test email?

Thank you in advance for your support and contributions.

Best regards,
Nico

Comment: continuing performing more tests, I added a valid ADO user ID as well, rewriting the "--data" value as:
```--data "{"message": { "to": {"tfIds": [$tfsid], "emailAddresses": ["my_email_address"],"unresolvedEntityIds": []},"subject": "cc","body": "test","cc": {"tfIds": [$tfsid]},"replyTo": {"tfIds": [$tfsid]}}}"```
and getting:
```{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: 6a1bd1de-97a4-4b14-a9c9-e4466f379f5a.","typeName":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException, Newtonsoft.Json","typeKey":"JsonReaderException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue when using `emailAddresses` in the request body. So far as I tested, the API only worked with `tfIds` defined in the body.

To get the `tfIds` given a user's email, we can use this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read-identities?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP).

Here is a sample PowerShell script in a YAML pipeline for your reference.

```
variables:
  orgName: ${{split(variables['System.CollectionUri'], 'https://dev.azure.com/')[1] }}

steps:
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Build.RequestedFor $(Build.RequestedFor)"
    Write-Host "Build.RequestedForEmail $(Build.RequestedForEmail)"
    Write-Host "Build.RequestedForId $(Build.RequestedForId)"
    $apiVersion = '7.2-preview.1'
    $headers = @{
        'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + "$(System.AccessToken)"
        'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    }
    # Get user's TFID
    $idURL = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$(orgName)/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue=$(Build.RequestedForEmail)&api-version=$apiVersion"
    $identity = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $idURL -Method Get -Headers $headers
    $tfid = $identity.value.id
    Write-Host User TFID is $tfid
    
    # Send email
    $emailURL = "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/wit/sendmail?api-version=$apiVersion"
    $body = @"
    {
        "message": {
            "to": {
                "tfIds":["$tfid"]
            },
            "subject":"Send email via API $(Build.BuildId) - Work Item 259",
            "cc":{
                "tfIds":["$tfid"]
            },
            "replyTo":{
                "tfIds":["$tfid"]
            }
        },
        "ids": [
            259
        ],
        "fields": [
            "System.WorkItemType",
            "System.Title",
            "System.State",
            "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort",
            "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue",
            "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea",
            "System.Tags"
        ],
        "format": 1
    }
    "@
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $emailURL -Method Post -Body $body -Headers $headers
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your code! I really appreciated it and it helped me to correctly deploy the same on BASH.
I'll share my code soon here!

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't receive a specific answer to my help request (BASH related), I decided to dive deeper into the issue and share my experience here. Hopefully, it can be helpful to others facing the same problem. I structured my code (an extract) as:

```
    # This line queries the Azure DevOps organization to determine the TFsid associated with a specific email address. TFsid represents the unique identifier within the Azure DevOps
    # organization, allowing precise identification and management of user accounts and their associated permissions and access rights.
    tfsid=$(curl --request GET "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$Organization/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue=$EmailAddress&api-version=7.2-preview.1" \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" | jq -r '.value[0] .id')
             
    # This line creates a new Work Item, specifically a Task, within the Azure DevOps project. The ID(s) of the newly created Work Item is stored in a variable, enabling subsequent
    # reference and tracking of the created task(s) within the pipeline or associated processes.
    ids=$(curl --request POST "https://dev.azure.com/$Organization/$Project/_apis/wit/workitems/\$task?api-version=7.2-preview.3" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json'  \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" \
    --data '[{"op": "add","path": "/fields/System.Title","from": null,"value": "Text'"}]' | jq -r '.id')

    # This line modifies the previously created Work Item, adding the text plan as a comment
    curl --request PATCH "https://dev.azure.com/$Organization/$Project/_apis/wit/workitems/$ids?api-version=7.2-preview.3" \
   --header "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" \
   --header "Authorization: Bearer $SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" \
   --data '[{"op": "test","path": "/rev","value": 1},{"op": "add","path": "/fields/System.AreaPath","value": "Customer_Project"},{"op": "add","path": "/fields/System.History","value": "'"$TEXT_HTML"'"}]'
              
    # This line sends an email notification to the email address defined at the beginning of the script. The email contains important information including the IDs of the
    # created Work Items. This notification ensures that stakeholders are promptly informed about the progress and details of the infrastructure changes initiated by the pipeline.    
    curl --request POST "https://dev.azure.com/$Organization/$Project/_apis/wit/sendmail?api-version=7.2-preview.1" \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data "{"message":{\"to\":{\"tfIds\":[\"$tfsid\"]},\"subject\":\"Text: \",\"body\":\"Check the following Work Item\",\"cc\":{\"tfIds\":[\"$tfsid\"]},\"replyTo\":{\"tfIds\":[\"$tfsid\"]}},\"ids\":[$ids]}"
```

and the following are all the link related to the Azure DevOps documentation:

- **Query for TFsid**: It performs a query against the Azure DevOps organization to ascertain the TFsid (Azure Devops id former Team Foundation Server id) that correlates with a specific email address. This step ensures that subsequent actions, such as notifications and work item assignments, are accurately targeted.
  [More information on Microsoft Learn : Identities - Read Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read-identities?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP)
- **Create Task Work Item**: Leveraging the information gleaned from the above  point, the script proceeds to create a new Task-type Work Item within the Azure DevOps project.
  [More information on Microsoft Learn : Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)
- **Update Task**: In a crucial follow-up action, the newly created Task Work Item is updated to include the comment (*TEXT_HTML* variable).
  [More information on Microsoft Learn : Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)
- **Email Notification**: Finally, with the tasks created and updated, an email notification is dispatched to the initially defined email address (*EmailAddress* variable). This email includes the IDs of the newly created Work Items.
  [More information on Microsoft Learn : Send Mail - Send Mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/send-mail/send-mail?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)